# Get list of nodenames in PostgreSQL XPATH

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath

PostgreSQL 14. Trying to extract all the node names from xml element:

```
SELECT xpath('./*/name()', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')
```

does not work

```
SELECT xpath('./*/text()', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')
```

works

```
SELECT xpath('name()', unnest(xpath('./*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'))
```

offered as solution gives empty list.

example:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//*/text()', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'))
```

will work

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//*/name()', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'))
```

will not

```
SELECT xpath('//text()', unnest(xpath('/foo/*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')))::varchar
```

works

```
SELECT xpath('//name()', unnest(xpath('/foo/*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')))::varchar
```

does not work
what is wrong with `name()`, `local-name()`, `namespace-uri()` functions? How to get a list of nodes within Postgres without parsing it outside? thanks

Comment: What about using a regex? `regexp_matches('<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>', '(<[a-zA-Z]+>)', 'g');`

Comment: impossible in my case, i'm parsing quite complicated structure with xmltable and json object in one request. This simple example just to illustrate point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this solution can bypass the problem. For some reason direct call of `name()` function is not working in `xpath()` function in latest versions of postgres.

```
SELECT * 
FROM xmltable('//*' PASSING '<foo><bar>text</bar></foo>'
            COLUMNS
            name varchar PATH 'name()'
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works on Postgres 9.6. Please notice xpath is `//*`

```
SELECT xpath('name()', unnest(xpath('//*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')));
```

Result

```
xpath
-----
{foo}
{bar}
{zar}
```

This XPath also works: `/* | /*//*`

Comment: SELECT x::varchar FROM (SELECT xpath('name()', unnest(xpath('//*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'))) AS x) AS xt
gives empty list in postgres 14

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT  unnest(xpath('//*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>'));`?

Comment: ```
xpath
|===|
|{""}|
|{""}|
|{""}|
|---|
```
sorry for formatting

Comment: Please try the second posted xpath.

Comment: unnest                                    |
------------------------------------------+
<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>|
<bar>test</bar>                           |
<zar>test1</zar>                          |

Comment: exception occurs only with name() local-name() and namespace-uri() functions and it seems that behaviour was changed somewhere between v9 and v.14

Comment: please try `name(.)` or `name(current())`

Comment: same result: empty values of xml type. name(current()) gives invalid xpath exception

Comment: `SELECT xpath('name(.)', x.nodes) from (SELECT unnest(xpath('//*', '<foo><bar>test</bar><zar>test1</zar></foo>')) as nodes) AS X;`

Comment: same empty list